# onSwipe Event is not Triggered inside a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, drawerlayout

*Please see update below*
I have a `ViewPager`, the first page(`fragment`) of it has a `DrawerLayout` that implements a `SimpleOnGestureListener` that listens to `onSwipe` event. The purpose of the `onSwipe` event inside the `DrawerLayout`(fragment) is to listen if the user swipes to `left` and `right` which triggers the opening and closing of the `drawer`. [image]

The problem is by the time, I swipe to `left or right` the *ViewPager's page changes* instead of triggering the opening and closing of the `Drawer`.

Is there a way to **disable** temporarily the swiping of the `ViewPager`, while its current view is on `DrawerLayout` so that it can listen to the left and right event?

If the Drawer is *opened* and If I swipe the screen to the right then that's the time the page changes. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now.

I this possible inside the `DrawerLayoutFragment`?

```
if(MainClass_ViewPager.getView == getActivity().getView)
MainClass_ViewPager.isEnabled(false)

onSwipe of `DrawerLayoutFragment`  is triggered
```

---

**Drawer**

```
public class DrawerLayoutFragment extends Fragment implements SimpleGestureListener{

   private SimpleGestureFilter detector; 

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return rootView;
    }

     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            return getActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

     @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

             // The action bar home/u p action should open or close the drawer.
             // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

                return true;
            }
            // Handle action buttons
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
            default:
                Log.d("onOptionsItemSelected", "inside");
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }


     protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

     @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }



    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);

            Log.d("DrawerItemClickListener", "inside");
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

   }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    //Simple Gesture
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
      this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
     return getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(me); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        Log.d("onSwipe", "onSwipe");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("onDoubleTap", "onDoubleTap");

    }

}
```

**UPDATE** - this is what I got so far. I have a parent ViewPager that has a child ViewPager(fragment), I can't handle the swiping of the *child ViewPager* because the parent one is always got swiped not giving any chance for the child one. The drawer is working, as along as I hold the left side of the screen for a sec then drag it to the right. As shown in the image above.

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
     Log.d("selectItem", "inside");
       // update the main content by replacing fragments
       ViewPagerConnect fragment = new ViewPagerConnect();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt("position", position);
       fragment.setArguments(args);

       FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
         ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
         ft.commit();

       // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
       mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
       setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
       mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
   }

---------------------------------------


public class ViewPagerConnect extends SherlockFragment{

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
     ViewPager mViewPager;
     static int position;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        position = getArguments().getInt("position");

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_connect, container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);


                return rootView;

    }

    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section: " + (position + 1);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
             switch(arg0){
             case 0:
                 PlanetFragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
                 Bundle args = new Bundle();
                 args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
                 fragment.setArguments(args);
                 return fragment;

             }
            return null;

        }
    }

}
----------------------------------------------
public class PlanetFragment extends SherlockFragment {

     ViewPager mViewPager;
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
---------------------------
viewpager_connect.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

-----------------------------------------------
fragment_planet.xml

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="32dp" />
```

Comment: I think you should not have a DrawerLayout inside of a ViewPager. It really should be used for high-level navigation, not for content screens. I would recommend putting it outside the ViewPager instead.

Comment: Are there any hack on this that we can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the demo NavDrawer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

If you swap in a ViewPager implementation for the Planet Selection frame given in the sample code, it will work fine.

Details:

in 'selectItem' just get a ViewPager in the 'fragment' object that is the target of the FragmentManager transaction.  That will do it and you will have the NavDrawer along with the ViewPager. Dont disable anything because it will just work.

see the 'planetfragement' below - just swap in your ViewPager class and it will all work. Remove the planetfragment. Add your ViewPager in its place.  that is all u have to do. Your 'viewpager' should be a Fragment that gets a ViewPager and hooks it up to an adapter. It implements the same interface as the Planets in the current sample. just swap it in.

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the `NavDrawer` example is my code. Can you provide a little code on this sir, I am not sure If I understood it well. Just to confirm I will do `extends FragmentPagerAdapter` in `Planet Fragment`?

Comment: If u have a working ViewPager then just put it in the sample code and it will work. If you dont have a working viewpager then clear that up before you try to slide it in alongside the NavDrawer.

Comment: To confirm my understanding, I will be creating a viewPager class which is a fragment that will be used together with the `NavDrawer`.

Comment: Please see sirr if I've done it correctly here. http://pastie.org/8223793 It display the same thing. http://oi42.tinypic.com/16m966b.jpg

Comment: When I tried to swipe it changes the page, and the drawer did not open.

Comment: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-YkHZSraHxZ8/UgZQUWFxqlI/AAAAAAAAHHU/NTLuRrCYxe8/w426-h682/scns_drwr_layout.png   is picture of ViewPager underneath a lft-side drawerLayout with the blue tracer for the swipe action turned on.

Comment: Good day sir, I added a picture above. Right now, I have a ViewPager inside a ViewPager. I followed what you've said and I got the view working but I can't handle the two ViewPager at the same time.

Comment: I addition, I have updated my question post above see update.

Comment: Following from your suggestion, I was able to add some work around. Thanks for this! :)